# Comparisons for quicksort are always 2 less than array size, normal?

Tags: java, counter, quicksort

without fail, array size 5000, 4998 comparisons. [32] = 30 comparisons, etc.

(edit for different condition:)
same for odd sized arrays: [35] makes count 33.

I could go on and on.

Why is this? Var is qcount.

I don't believe there are any comparisons in the partition though perhaps I am wrong on that. My classmate is getting numbers about 80 times as large at times, so there is a huge difference in our counts.

My code works though. So that's good. Just the counts are vastly different.

Thanks for reading. SO made me write more when I really don't need to.

```
public class QuickSortTest
  {

static int numcalls = 0;
static int qcount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random gen = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[5000];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        array[i] = gen.nextInt(5000) + 1;
      }
    System.out.println("Initial array:");
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
      }
    System.out.println();
    quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    System.out.println("Sorted array:");
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
      }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println("qcount " + qcount);
  }

public static int partition(int stuff[], int a, int z)
  {
    int left = a, right = z;
    int saveStuff;
    int pivot = stuff[(a + z) / 2];

    while (left <= right)
      {
        while (stuff[left] < pivot)
          {
            left++;
          }
        while (stuff[right] > pivot)
          {
            right--;
          }
        if (left <= right)
          {
            saveStuff = stuff[left];
            stuff[left] = stuff[right];
            stuff[right] = saveStuff;
            left++;
            right--;
          }
      };
    return left;
  }

public static void quicksort(int stuff[], int a, int z)
  {
    int index = partition(stuff, a, z);
    if (a < index - 1)
      {
        quicksort(stuff, a, index - 1);
        qcount++;
      }
    if (index < z)
      {
        quicksort(stuff, index, z);
        qcount++;
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: @MattBall strangely enough it was. count for [35] was 33.

Is that odd?

Comment: It does seem a bit odd, given that [comparison-based sorting algorithms have a lower bound of `Ω(n log(n))` comparisons.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques)

Comment: @MattBall I know it's supposed to be *best case* nlogn which is why this is so strange. Where should the count go then? It DOES work however. Which makes this stranger.

Comment: `qcount++` should go on every fair comparison you do using the elements of your array or that affects them. For example: `while (stuff[left] < pivot)`, `while (stuff[right] > pivot)`, `if (left <= right)`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza bah! That's what I thought at first then someone told me no. Should have figured since that made no sense to me. It still stays where it is, correct?

Thanks, I feel validated.

Comment: I would remove the addition of `qcount` in these cases: `if (a < index - 1)`, `if (index < z)`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you explain why you take those out? Is it because it is being compared to the index and not to the actual number in the array? The index is just a middle value that does not necessarily need to be within the array, but is always in the range of it.

Comment: Yes but is not a meaningful comparison that will directly affect the order of the elements in the array. The other cases, in fact, have a direct impact (even if the array is not modified).

Comment: If you have two elements you need one comparison.  I would start with the simplest example which shows your problem and use your debugger to debug it.